# How to manually handle Spring 4 transactions?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-test

How to programmatically control transaction boundaries within single `@Test` method? Spring 4.x documentation has some [clues](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-tx-programmatic-tx-mgt) but I think I missing something since the test throws error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot start a new transaction without ending the existing transaction first.
```

**Test**

```
import com.hibernate.query.performance.config.ApplicationConfig;
import com.hibernate.query.performance.config.CachingConfig;
import com.hibernate.query.performance.persistence.model.LanguageEntity;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TestTransaction;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.util.List;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ApplicationConfig.class, CachingConfig.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@PersistenceContext
@Transactional(transactionManager = "hibernateTransactionManager")
@TestExecutionListeners({})
public class EHCacheTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EHCacheTest.class);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        logger.info("setUpBeforeClass()");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        logger.info("tearDownAfterClass()");
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Test
    public void testTransactionCaching(){
        TestTransaction.start();
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        System.out.println(session.get(LanguageEntity.class, 1));
        Query query = session.createQuery("from LanguageEntity le where le.languageId < 10").setCacheable(true).setCacheRegion("language");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<LanguageEntity> customerEntities = query.list();
        System.out.println(customerEntities);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
        TestTransaction.end();

        // Second Transaction
        TestTransaction.start();

        Session sessionNew =  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        System.out.println(sessionNew.get(LanguageEntity.class, 1));
        Query anotherQuery = sessionNew.createQuery("from LanguageEntity le where le.languageId < 10");
        anotherQuery.setCacheable(true).setCacheRegion("language");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<LanguageEntity> languagesFromCache = anotherQuery.list();
        System.out.println(languagesFromCache);
        sessionNew.getTransaction().commit();

        TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
        TestTransaction.end();
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

One more detail:

All occurences `session.getTransaction().commit();` **must** be removed since they interrupt transaction workflow.

Comment: You can safely delete the following since they are superfluous in this context: `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`, `@TestExecutionListeners({})`.

Comment: Furthermore, `@PersistenceContext` has no meaning on a test class. So you can safely delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL;DR

---

In order to avoid this problem, just remove the first line of the test method and use the already available transaction:

```
@Test
public void testTransactionCaching() {
    // Remove this => TestTransaction.start(); 
    // Same as before
}
```

---

## Detailed Answer

When you annotate your test class with `@Transactional` or extending the `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`:

```
// Other annotations
@Transactional(transactionManager = "hibernateTransactionManager")
public class EHCacheTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests { ... }
```

Each test method within that class will be run within a transaction. To be more precise, *Spring Test Context* (By using `TransactionalTestExecutionListener`) would open a transaction in the beginning of each test method and roll it back after completion of the test.

So, your `testTransactionCaching` test method:

```
@Test
public void testTransactionCaching() { ... }
```

Would have an open transaction in the beginning and you're trying to open another one manually by:

```
TestTransaction.start();
```

Hence the error:

> Cannot start a new transaction without ending the existing transaction
>   first.

In order to avoid this problem, just remove the first line of the test method and use that already available transaction. The other `TestTransaction.*` method calls are OK but just remove the first one.

Comment: Very good answer, except the part about `@TestExecutionListeners({})`. `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` is annotated with `@TestExecutionListeners`. Thus, the empty declaration on the test class simply appends _nothing_ to the already declared listeners. In other words, it has zero effect and does not disable `TransactionalTestExecutionListener`.

Comment: @SamBrannen thanks sam for your feedback...I edited the answer